# Difference between "magnitude" and "multitude"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *magnitude* and *multitude*?

> Quantity is a kind of property which exists as **magnitude** or **multitude**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnitude

Definition: Extent of dimensions; size; applied to things that have length, breath, and thickness.

Multitude
Definition : The state of being many; numerousness.

For more details you can follow these links -

Link 1 : [Magnitude](http://ardictionary.com/Magnitude/446)
Link 2 : [Multitude](http://thinkexist.com/dictionary/meaning/multitude/)

Hope it'll help :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the example sentence, *magnitude* is used to refer to size (how big) while *multitude* is used to refer to numbers (how many).

Comment: However, "multitude" is rather rare in this sense: "number" is a more common way of expressing it. The main sense of "multitude" is a somewhat literary word for a large collection of something, rather than the property of its largeness. "And there were multitudes of angels, singing". This is also the sense in the idiom "(something) hides a multitude of sins/evils", meaning that the thing (eg a coat of paint) covers up lots of problems (not really sins or evil things).